# First and second derivative of $|x|^3$

Tags: limits, derivatives, absolute-value

I need to prove that $|x|^3$ is twice differentiable, by showing that the first and second derivatives exist using the definition. I've tried several ways, this is what I've got:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|x+h|^3 - |x|^3}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)^2}^3 - \sqrt{x^2}^3}{h}  = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{(x+h)^6} - \sqrt{x^6}}{h}$$

then I rationalized the numerator:

$$= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h)^6 - x^6}{h\left(\sqrt{(x+h)^6} + \sqrt{x^6}\right)}$$

and I'm stuck on what to do next, I'm skeptic that this is the right way, but I was not able to reach any answer using other ways either.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the concept of left and right limit. That will simplify your square roots considerably, and you will be able to understand more clearly, why the function is exactly twice differentiable, and not say four or five times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At $x\ne0$, you can take $h$ so small that $x$ and $x+h$ have the same sign. Then the function can be processed as two polynomial pieces which derive seamlessly:

$$|x^3|=\pm x^3$$ gives the derivatives $$\pm3x^2=3x|x|$$ and $$\pm6x=6|x|$$ (as the $\pm$ signs match that of $x$).

At $x=0$, the first derivative is

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|h^3|}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\pm h^2=0$$

(the sign doesn't matter as convergence is to zero). Note that the first derivative is continous as $3x|x|$ evaluates to $0$.

The second derivative is given by

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3h|h|}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}3|h|=0.$$

---

Note that for the third derivative we get

$$\pm6$$ where the sign is that of $x$, and for $x=0$,

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{6|h|}{h}$$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just separate the last limit, i.e.,
\begin{aligned}
L&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^6 - x^6}{h\left(\sqrt{(x+h)^6} + \sqrt{x^6}\right)}\\ &= 
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^6 - x^6}{h}\cdot \lim_{h\to 0}{\frac1{\sqrt{(x+h)^6} + \sqrt{x^6}}} \\&= \frac{\mathrm{d}x^6}{\mathrm{d}x}\cdot\frac1{2\sqrt{x^6}}
\\&= 6x^5\cdot\frac1{2|x^3|} \\ &=6x^5\cdot\frac{1}{2x^2|x|}
\\ &=3\frac{x^3}{|x|}
\end{aligned}
and you're done.

If you need to prove $\frac{\mathrm{d}x^6}{\mathrm{d}x}=6x^5$, you can use this \begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x^6}{\mathrm{d}x}&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^6-x^6}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h-x)\left((x+h)^5+x(x+h)^4+x^2(x+h)^3+x^3(x+h)^2+x^4(x+h)+x^5\right)}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h\left((x+h)^5+x(x+h)^4+x^2(x+h)^3+x^3(x+h)^2+x^4(x+h)+x^5\right)}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\left((x+h)^5+x(x+h)^4+x^2(x+h)^3+x^3(x+h)^2+x^4(x+h)+x^5\right)\\
&=6x^5
\end{aligned}

Comment: thank you. but this assumes that we know the derivative of $x^6$